# Under what circumstance would setting MaxDop to anything other than 1 cause an issue?

Tags: sql-server, maxdop

we are having continued discussions with our vendor whom is insistent on setting MaxDop to 1

we have performed internal testing and see a general 20% performance improvement by setting this to 4 with cost threshold to 50

we suspect they may be other motives of insisting setting of 1.

I'm unsure what they maybe however.

** EDIT:: to make the question more specific, is there a scenario where by setting maxdop to anything other than 1 cause errors to occur**

- Microsoft Guidance
  https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2806535
- relevant Paul Randall post
  http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/maxdop-configuration-survey-results/
- Brent Ozar on CX packet waits
  http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/08/what-is-the-cxpacket-wait-type-and-how-do-you-reduce-it/

Comment: Why don't you ask them about their motivation?  They are the only ones who can tell you *why* they are insistent.

Comment: We have and they have yet to provide any substantial evidence of a reason

Comment: Why do you think we will guess their reason(s) correctly?

Comment: hi aaron, i do not, i was looking for a little insight into other peoples experiences and at best something i could read into that expanded on my understanding of MaxDOP and would help in hte conversation to try to persuade them to support somethign other than 1.

Comment: i.e. under what particular scenario would they suggest maxdop 1 i.e. poor indexing and large tables

Comment: We had (on Azure Managed Instance) attempted to set the MaxDOP to 1; and had Full Text Search immediately grind to a halt.  It probably shouldn't have, I fully blame Azure for that particular quirk, but managing Full Text on a server where you can't just bounce the Full Text Daemon when you want/need is a struggle.  Just my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are installing any specific Microsoft application such as [SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/SharePoint/administration/best-practices-for-sql-server-in-a-sharepoint-server-farm) or [BizTalk](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/biztalk/technical-guides/checklist-maintaining-and-troubleshooting-biztalk-server-databases), setting `MAXDOP = 1` server wide is not a good choice.

There is a [good and repeatable way to calculate MAXDOP on SQL Server](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/36578/8783) based on [Microsoft best practice](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-max-degree-of-parallelism-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver16).

Also, refer to [How It Works: Maximizing Max Degree Of Parallelism (MAXDOP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/psssql/how-it-works-maximizing-max-degree-of-parallelism-maxdop)

My recommendation is to ask your vendor, why they would need it at server instance level as opposed to query level. Also, look into adjusting `cost threshold for parallelism` which is by default set to 5. [Cost threshold of parallelism](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/49121/8783) refers to what the minimum query cost has to be before Parallelism is considered by the optimizer.

Comment: thank kin i was aware of the reccomendation for sharepoint my understanding is this is because sharepoint is particularly bad for table scans

Answer (score -1):

In a highly transactional environment MAXDOP=1 can be an advantage.

It's not really your vendors business what your sever setting is. If their application queries need MAXDOP 1 suggest query hints. Your vendors expectation that you'll make a server wide change for the application is unreasonable.

Comment: `It's not really your vendors business what your sever setting is.`  It absolutely is if it breaks your support agreement.